# Quotes for string keys in config file glib

Tags: c, linux, glibc, glib

I want to use `g_key_file_get_string` from linux glib library to read string between quotes from configuration file and ignore them.

Now i'm using `string_key=value` but i want to use `string_key="value"` in configuration file
and when i call:
`conf->value = g_key_file_get_string(gkf, "GENERAL_CONFIG","string_key", &error);`

i expect to have `value` in variable `conf->value`, without "".
I belive that exist a specific function to do that(if not i will remove the quotes manualy);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `glib`, you are probably looking for [g_shell_unquote()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.38/glib-Shell-related-Utilities.html#g-shell-unquote).